# Netlify Function cannot import relative .graphql type definition file

Tags: lambda, graphql, apollo-server, netlify, prisma

I've just rewritten a Node.js GraphQL API from an old version of graphql-yoga + prisma to using express, serverless-http, prisma, and apollo-server-express. I've got it working locally just fine as an Express app, but when I try to get it published on Netlify as Function, I get a "Cannot find module" error:

```
{
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './schema.graphql'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/bundle/index.js\n- /var/task/graphql.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
"trace": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './schema.graphql'",
"Require stack:",
"- /var/task/bundle/index.js",
"- /var/task/graphql.js",
"- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
"- /var/runtime/index.js",
"    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
"    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
"    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
"    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)",
"    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)",
"    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)",
"    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)",
"    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)",
"    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47"
]
}
```

I've tried multiple ways of importing these graphql files (graphql-imports, require.resolve, fs.readDirSync, etc.), but either it doesn't work at all or it only works from the project root. `require.resolve` works from the project root locally, so I'm left thinking that this file just wasn't included in the build. How can I tell what gets zipped?

My netlify.toml is:

```
[build]
  command = "npm run bundle"
  functions = "functions"
```

`npm run bundle` is basically `cpx 'src/**/*' 'functions/bundle'`and the files are visible locally in `functions/bundle/schema.graphql` and `functions/bundle/generated/prisma.graphql`.

My `functions/graphql.js` just takes the Express server and creates a lambda wrapper:

```
const serverlessHttp = require("serverless-http");

const { app } = require("./bundle/index.js");

exports.handler = serverlessHttp(app, {
  request(req, event, context) {
    req.event = event;
    req.context = context;
  }
});
```

"graphql-import" is super annoying because it only works from the root for the project, so copying the `src/` files into `functions/bundle/` changes the directory structure and those imports no longer work
Inside the functions/bundle/index.js, I try to `require.resolve` some .grapqhl type definition files:

```
const { importSchema } = require("graphql-import");

const typeDefs = importSchema(require.resolve("./schema.graphql"));
const prismaTypeDefs = importSchema(
  require.resolve("./generated/prisma.graphql")
);

const db = new Prisma({
  typeDefs: prismaTypeDefs,
  endpoint: process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT,
  secret: process.env.PRISMA_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: gql`
    ${typeDefs}
  `,
  resolvers: {
    Mutation,
    Query,
  },
  resolverValidationOptions: { requireResolversForResolveType: false }
});
```

Again, this works locally so I assume the file is just outright missing from the zipped files.

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried testing locally but with the netlify environment via `netlify functions:invoke`? It can help to debug such issues. (See https://github.com/netlify/cli/blob/master/docs/netlify-dev.md#locally-testing-functions-with-netlify-functionsinvoke)

Regarding your issue it seems certain files are ignored as you already suggested:

> Netlify will access the functions directory
>   during every deploy, zipping and deploying each supported code file as
>   a serverless Lambda function on AWS. (Note that, with one exception,
>   any files in subdirectories will be ignored.)

To use multiple files you need to define a folder with the function name and the js in it within your functions folder, otherwise it will only consider the .js file:

> You can use either a standalone .js file that exports a handler (e.g.
>   functions/{function_name}.js) or a folder with the same name as a .js
>   file in it that exports a handler (e.g.
>   functions/{function_name}/{function_name}.js).

Make sure to use relative imports or consider the full path.

Also you could try deploying unbundled JavaScript starting with CLI version 2.7.0. See: https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#unbundled-javascript-function-deploys